# Group by null in MariaDB

Tags: group-by, null, mariadb

1. I have a table with data like the one below.

   ```
   **  ID  TYP       NAME      END**
        1  *null*  ADEPLAST    S.R.L.
        2  *null*  ADEPLAST    S.A.      
        3   S.C.   ADEPLAST    S.R.L.
        4   A.B.   ADEPLAST    S.R.L.
   ```
2. Is there a way in MariaDB to group it so that i get a result like:

   ```
   **  ID  TYP       NAME      END**
       1,3 S.C.   ADEPLAST    S.R.L.
       2  *null*  ADEPLAST    S.A.
       4   A.B.   ADEPLAST    S.R.L.
   ```
3. I have tried the classical GROUP BY, but as i have read somewhere, the NULL value is a value in itself so that won't work

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=3f399e7828f89328dc6a7161baadb18d)

```
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as `ID`,
   `TYP`,
   `NAME`,
   `END`
FROM (
   -- this will find the TYP when it is NULL, and the same name with 
   -- a TYPE exists
   SELECT
      ID,
      CASE WHEN `TYP` IS NULL THEN (SELECT TYP 
                                  FROM table1 t1 
                                  WHERE t1.name=t0.name 
                                    and t1.`END`=t0.`END` 
                                    and NOT t1.TYP IS NULL
                                    LIMIT 1) 
                            ELSE TYP END as `TYP`,
      Name,
      `END`
   FROM table1 t0
   
) x
GROUP BY `TYP`,`Name`,`END`
ORDER BY `ID`
```

Comment: i am a human being so i use words: thank you very much :)